# Obtener combinación maxima entre un valor y una lista

Tags: python

Me gustaria crear una funcion que haga lo siguiente:

por ejemplo

`l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14]` y `a = 3`

me gustaria pasar hacer `a % l[i]` con cada elemento de la lista, y saber con que `l[i]` obtenendre el valor mas alto para esta operacion, es decir, que la funcion retorne el elemento de la lista con la cual la operacion `a % elemento` sea la mas grande. Si el resultado es el mismo con todos los elementos, debera devolver el valor en la posicion mas cercana al 0.

No se me ocurre como hacerlo! Ayuda porfavor

Comment: Deberías poner algo de código, o lo que has intentado, o pensado, para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

si he entendido bien el enunciado, creo que algo así te serviría:

```
def your_function(new_list, value):

    last_value=0

    for counter, element in enumerate(new_list):

        if(a%element>last_value):

            last_value = counter

    return last_value


l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14]

a = 3

print(your_function(l, a))
```